# How to solve this indeterminate form?

Tags: limits, analysis

Let $a_1(n)=n$, $a_k(n)=2+\sqrt{a_{k-1}(n)},k\ge2$, then can we determine the limit of the following indeterminate form
$$
\lim_{k\to+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{a_k(2)}}}{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{a_k(3)}}}.
$$

I have no idea to solve it, and I tried to calculate it in Matlab, and the answer maybe is $\frac{3}{2}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By shifting the index by one, we may assume the sequence starts at $k = 0$.

Then for $a_0(x) = x \in [0, 4]$, write $a_k(x) = 4\cos^2\theta_k(x)$ for $\theta_k(x) \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$. Then

$$ \cos^2\theta_k(x) = \frac{a_k(x)}{4} = \frac{2+\sqrt{a_{k-1}(x)}}{4} = \frac{2+2\cos\theta_{k-1}(x)}{2} = \cos^2 \frac{\theta_{k-1}(x)}{2}. $$

Repeatedly applying this equality, we get $\cos \theta_k(x) = \cos \frac{\theta_0(x)}{2^k}$ and hence $\theta_k(x) = \frac{1}{2^k}\theta_0(x)$. Then

$$ \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{a_k(x)}} = \sqrt{2 - 2\cos\theta_k(x)} = 2\sin\frac{\theta_k(x)}{2} = 2\sin\frac{\theta_0(x)}{2^{k+1}}. $$

Hence for $x, y \in [0, 4]$ with $y \neq 4$,

$$ \sqrt{\frac{2 - \sqrt{a_k(x)}}{2 - \sqrt{a_k(y)}}} = \frac{\sin(\theta_0(x)/2^{k+1})}{\sin(\theta_0(y)/2^{k+1})} \to \frac{\theta_0(x)}{\theta_0(y)} = \frac{\arccos(\sqrt{x}/2)}{\arccos(\sqrt{y}/2)}. $$

When $x = 2$ and $y = 3$, this reduces to

$$ \frac{\arccos(1/\sqrt{2})}{\arccos(\sqrt{3}/2)} = \frac{\pi/4}{\pi/6} = \frac{3}{2}. $$

Comment: Thank you! This is indeed a good answer.